# Order a table by column and get row number

Tags: sql, mysql, wordpress

In my database, I have table `wp_postmeta`, example:

```
| meta_key | meta_value |  post_id   |
---------------------------------
   points  |     12     |  23
   points  |     2      |  18
   lorem   |     ipsum  |  92
   points  |     8      |  15
```

I want to order `points` by `meta_value` and get the row number of a specific `post_id`. Basically a rank system, with highest number at the top.

For example, ordering `points` by `meta_value`:

```
| meta_key | meta_value |  post_id   |
---------------------------------
   points  |     12     |  23
   points  |     8      |  15
   points  |     2      |  18
```

`post_id` with value `15` will be **rank 2**.

What SQL query can I run to achieve this *with* optimisation in mind?

### What I've tried so far

I have achieved this via query:

```
$query="
    SELECT post_id,FIND_IN_SET(
                  post_id,(SELECT GROUP_CONCAT( post_id ORDER BY meta_value * 1 DESC)
                          FROM $wpdb->postmeta
                          WHERE meta_key ='points')
                       ) AS `rank`
    FROM $wpdb->postmeta
    WHERE meta_key ='points'
    AND post_id = '".$post_id."'
    ";

$result  = $wpdb->get_row($query);

$rank = $result->rank;
```

Works fine. *However*, this query is very slow.

How can I make this query faster?

EDIT: Here is a list of indexes in this table:

[image]

Comment: Doesn't mysql now have `ROW_NUMBER()`?

Comment: @choroba Can you please post an answer using `ROW_NUMBER()` with my code as reference?

Comment: I don't believe that there is enough context to actually answer this question.  What are the inputs?  What indexes do you have on the table?  Please read the SQL tag wiki and provide the requested information.  Note also that for many applications (e.g. a top ten list), it would be better to select the rank as part of the listing query.

Comment: @mdfst13 List of indexes in this table: https://i.imgur.com/QReQbZj.png

Answer (score 1):

I would create a [covering index](https://stackoverflow.com/q/609343/6660678) on `meta_key`, `meta_value`, `post_id` and see if that helps.

Note that you currently only have a prefix key on the meta_key column.  So you will probably have to make both meta_key and meta_value prefixes and you may have to limit them to a combined length of 186 (assuming you need 20 for the post_id).  That certainly works for the example, where you could get by with

```
CREATE INDEX meta_key_value_post_id_idx ON wp_postmeta ( meta_key(7), meta_value(21), post_id )
```

You may or may not need longer values for `meta_value` and/or `meta_key` for other queries.  But if you only ever query for 'points' and it always has numeric values with twenty digits or fewer, this should work.  Because it's enough to match points uniquely (7 bytes is more than the six one-byte characters in points, so it won't match things like pointsa) and numeric values (less than twenty ASCII digits).

[This post](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2357620/6660678) may help you determine what the maximum value length in the column is.  E.g.

```
SELECT MAX(LENGTH(meta_value)) FROM wp_postmeta WHERE meta_key = 'points';
```

Note:  this is assuming you use [@choroba's version](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/a/264047/71574).  I'm not sure that the index will help with `GROUP_CONCAT`.

Answer (score 0):

Mysql supports the ROW_NUMBER() function.

```sql
SELECT rank
FROM (
    SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY meta_value) AS rank,
        meta_key, meta_value, post_id
    FROM wp_postmeta
    WHERE meta_key = 'points'
) AS r
WHERE post_id = 18;
```

But I'm not sure it performs any better than your solution.

Comment: Thanks. I ran a speed test on this vs my original approach, and there is barely any difference unfortunately. Is there an approach where the query will perform better?

Comment: Do you have any indices defined on the table?

Comment: Yes, this is the current index setup of this table: https://i.imgur.com/QReQbZj.png

Answer (score 0):

you could make use of variables and subqueries, something like this [SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/196528/5):

```
SET @rank := 0;
SELECT post_id, rank
FROM (
  SELECT *, @rank := @rank + 1 rank
  FROM (
    SELECT 
      post_id, 
      meta_value * 1 meta_value
    FROM 
      wp_postmeta 
    WHERE
      meta_key ='points'
  ) a 
  ORDER BY meta_value desc
) e
WHERE 
  post_id = 15
```

this will return :

```
| post_id | rank |
|---------|------|
|      15 |    2 |
```

Answer (score 0):

Sorry for bumping this old question, but I found it interesting and wanted to provide an alternative point of view.

To my understanding `post_meta` table is a bad place to store data which need to be queried or compared. I think this was due to `meta_value` column having `longtext` as its type - and the table itself getting bloated very easily. (*Someone more knowledgeable of sql databases can comment, if this is the case or not.*)

An alternative approach, which might be worth trying, is converting the meta values to posts. So you would have a custom post type `points` with the amount of points stored in the `menu_order` column (*int(11)*) and the relation to the actual post saved in `post_parent` (*bigint(20) unsigned*).

The query would then target the `$wpdb->posts` table where `post_type='points'` and `post_parent=$post_id` and order the results by `menu_order` column.

[WP Codex: Post table description & indexes](https://codex.wordpress.org/Database_Description#Table:_wp_posts)

Storing the data this way would of course require changes to how the points are stored. The custom post type could be registered as private (i.e. `'public' => false`) so it doesn't show up in the admin UI.